# setPeriodicityV2() is not working in Chart IQ Android

Tags: javascript, android, charts

I am using [Chart IQ](http://documentation.chartiq.com/index.html)  to draw chart in android, below code of java script file i am calling from native android code, but setPeriodicityV2() is not working

```
   function loadPeriod(period) {
    <!--console.log("data from java loadPeriod function : " + period);-->
    if ("1D" === period) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2(1,"day");
    } else if ("5D" === period) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2(5,"day");
    } else if ("3M" === period ) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2(3,"month");
    } else if ("6M" === period) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2(6,"month");
    } else if ("1Y" === period) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2(1,"year");
    } else if ("5Y" === period) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2(5,"year");
        <!--stxx.setPeriodicityV2(1,"day");-->
    } else if ("MAX" === period) {
        stxx.setPeriodicityV2("MAX","day");
        <!--stxx.setPeriodicityV2(1, "year");-->
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Jitendra,
I'm not clear on the intention of your code snippet.  A period is the period of time that each data point represents.  For example, a chart with a period of 1 Day is a chart consisting of daily data points.  However, your 'if' conditions suggest to me that possibly you are trying to set the time span of the chart.   The following tutorial and methods documentation should prove helpful.

http://documentation.chartiq.com/CIQ.ChartEngine.html#setPeriodicityV2
http://documentation.chartiq.com/CIQ.ChartEngine.html#setSpan

Also, check out our tutorial on "Range and Span".

Please direct further inquiries to dev@chartiq.com so that we can assist you in more detail with your particular implementation.

York